# What type declaration should I use to create my own HashMap contains method?

Tags: types, rust

I am trying to get my head around Rust's type system.

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn hs_contains<T>(hs: &HashSet<T>, value: &T) -> bool
where 
    T: PartialEq,
{
    hs.iter().any(|v| v == value)
}

fn main() {
    // move strings into HashSet
    let known_values: HashSet<&str> = ["a", "b", "c"].iter().cloned().collect();

    // provided an Vec<String>
    let provided_values: Vec<String> = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "z".to_string()];

    // hash set of refrences
    let mut found: HashSet<&str> = HashSet::new();
    found.insert(&provided_values[0]);
    found.insert(&provided_values[1]);
    found.insert(&provided_values[2]);

    let missing: HashSet<_> = known_values.difference(&found).collect();

    let value: &String = &provided_values[1];

    hs_contains(&known_values, value);
    hs_contains(&missing, "c");

    println!("missing: {:#?}", missing);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b410881f4b293ef01c6c711443011f8a))

The example code does not compile because types do not coerce. Is it possible to come up with a type declaration for `hs_contains` that will satisfy the conditions at the bottom of the example:

```rust
hs_contains(&known_values, value);
hs_contains(&missing, "c");
```

#### Why don't I just use `HashSet::contains`?

Replacing `hs_contains` with `HashSet::contains`

```rust
known_values.contains(value);
missing.contains(&"c");
```

Results in the following compile error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&str: std::borrow::Borrow<std::string::String>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:38:18
   |
38 |     known_values.contains(value);
   |                  ^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::borrow::Borrow<std::string::String>` is not implemented for `&str`
```

The only other way I know of to make this work is

```rust
known_values.iter().any(|v| v == value);
```

This pricked my interest in how to define a function with a type declaration that could encapsulate the above.

Comment: The built-in HashSet methods are more abstract and could be what you want. e.g. look at the type of [`HashSet::contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.contains). Applied to your code, might look like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=29e0708e2435537b9a915b0e88f3f450

Comment: The key question here is — why create your own in the first place instead of using the one `HashSet` provides?

Comment: @Shepmaster I have answered your question in my question.

Comment: `known_values.contains(&**value);` / `missing.contains(&"c");`

Answer (score 0):

One small change can make it compile: move the `&` from the function's declaration to inside the function's body

```rust
fn hs_contains<T>(hs: &HashSet<T>, value: T) -> bool
where
    T: std::cmp::PartialEq,
{
    hs.iter().any(|v| v == &value)
}
```

and add an `&` on the `"c"`

```rust
hs_contains(&missing, &"c" );
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f4707033a18cc2213459e8806706f54a))

---

Now why is moving `&` inside the function any different?

As explained by Max in the comments below

> When you use `<T>` and later `value:T` you ask rust to figure out what `T` really is. In your case it should be a reference to a `str`. When you use value `&T` you now ask for a reference to a reference of a `str` (a `&&str`)

Comment: When you use `<T>` and later `value:T` you ask rust to figure out what `T` really is. In your case it _shoulb be_ a reference to a `str`. When you use `value &T` you now ask for a reference to a reference of a `str` (a `&&str`). I think `value` (in ln. 30) can be casted into a `&str` but not into a `&&str`.

Comment: @Max Thank you for explaining that. `&&str` in you [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2047da23c92385fd7697f228ddf5b7b8) threw me. I realised that I needed to do a `cloned` to get `HashSet<&str>`. So where should `&` go?

Comment: Just to clarify: where the `&` go, I mean, should it be in the function declaration or inside the function body?